# Horizontal Progress Bar - How to add label inside indicator?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, material-components-android, linearprogressindicator

I'm using the material library's `LinearProgressIndicator` for a horizontal progress bar.

How would I add a label inside the indicator of the progressbar indicator?

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="65"
        app:trackColor="@color/background_color"
        app:trackThickness="16dp"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/black"/>
```

Comment: Have you considered putting a textview on top of it? Of course only if the height of the indicator view is high enough. Or you look for something else in particular?

Comment: I want it to be inside and following the left side of the indicator. I am aware there is a few libraries to do so, but I am wondering if there can be a simple solution (like an xml flag) instead of using an entire library for this problem.

Comment: By *I want it to be inside and following the left side of the indicator.* you mean that you want it to follow the indicator and it moves toward right as the indicator moves to completion? Or just want it to be static at the center only?

Comment: Yup, following the indicator

Comment: Aha I see, unfortunately there is no built-in API that can do something like this. But you can do some tricks such as putting a textview on top, moving the textview towards right by applying the progress value as an offset from the start of the textiew. This way the textview will slide towards right as the indicator value increments. You can even animate this movement but I'm not sure whether the animation can be fast enough to catch progress changes.

Comment: Oh okay. Seems like too much trouble to program. I think I will just use one of the libraries I found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ProgressView](https://github.com/skydoves/ProgressView) library. I think it is what you are looking for.

[image]